# Output the square root just for the whole numbers

Tags: java, output, square-root, math.sqrt

I need to Output the results of square root just for the whole numbers.

Example:

```
1  - 1
4  - 2
9  - 3
16 - 4...
```

up to `961 - 31`... Which is the last square root before 1000.

Until now I have this... But, this is showing square roots for all numbers until 1000, and I want the square root for **WHOLE NUMBERS ONLY**.

What should I do?

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        double i = 1;
        do {
            System.out.printf("%.0f\t%.0f\n", i, Math.sqrt(i));
            i++;
        } while (i <= 1000);
    }
}
```

The output that I want should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Consider looping `i` from 1 to `Math.sqrt(1000)` and printing `i` and `i*i`

Answer (score 1):

The trick that can solve your request is in the Math class too,

```
Math.floor(...)
```

that method will round a double to the lower integer, so you need to check if the root and the lower floor are the same..

## Example:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
            final double res = Math.sqrt(j);
            if (res == Math.floor(res)) {
                System.out.printf("%d\t%.0f\n", j, res);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that

Comment: sure, give a try and let e know

Answer (score 1):

It is not efficient to loop through all 1000 values. Instead, consider the following code:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= Math.sqrt(1000); i++) {
    System.out.println(i*i + " - " + i);
}
```

Comment: That's clever! Prints the perfect squares from 1 to 31.

Comment: Happy it helped! If this answered your question then please remember to accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
    double sqrt = Math.sqrt(i);
    if (sqrt % 1 == 0) {
        System.out.println(i + " " + (int) sqrt);
    }
}
```

For int values `sqrt % 1` will be equal to zero.

Comment: you are looping 1000 times but you only need 31 loops

Answer (score 0):

Your method of solving this problem is slightly flawed.

- You can know the biggest number immediately, it is the floor of the square root of the limit you have. So for `1000 => sqrt(1000) = 31.6`.... therefore the closest you will get with a whole number is 31 squared, anything bigger will be greater than 1000
- Also, you have a function, f`(x) = x^2` , but you are looping through `f(x)` values instead of x values, this will make for a much larger amount of tests.

I would just do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Math.sqrt(1000); i++) {
    System.out.println((i+1)^2 + " - " + i);
}
```